# Several values in a nested json dictionary/string in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, node-red

I'm attempting to build a json file that within a nested dictionary saves several sets of coordinates. These are supposed to be frameworks for json strings that will be variables in a node in Node-Red and then used by python scripts, here is an example of the strings:

```
koordinatstring = {
    "Coordinates":
    {
        "AllCoordinates":
        {
            "FirstCordinates":
            {
                "X": "1",
                "Y": "1"
            }
            "SecondCordinates":
            {
                "X": "2",
                "Y": "2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This does not work. However this structure works when just looking at a single set of variables.

```
koordinatstring = {
    "Coordinates":
    {
        "AllCoordinates":
        {
            "FirstCordinates":
            {
                "X": "1",
                "Y": "1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, how should I the string in the format the first example to actually be able to accept both values when I use them in Node-Red?

Comment: are you missing a comma before "secondcordinates"? you should check http://jsonlint.com/ first or something similar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a comma after `"FirstCordinates"` block, like this:

```
"FirstCordinates":
{
    "X": "1",
    "Y": "1"
},
```

Further explanation:
In Python, you declare dictionary like this:

```
my_dict = { "key1": "value1" }
```

If you have multiple key/value pairs, you separate them using comma.

```
my_dict = { 
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2" 
}
```

Instead of having a string `"value1"` as a value for `key1`, it can be another dictionary!

```
my_dict = { 
    "key1": 
    {
        "subkey1": "subvalue1"
    },
    "key2": "value2" 
}
```

But always, after a key/value pair, there has to be comma if another key/pair follows it (no need for comma if it's the last one, but it doesn't hurt).

Instead of having a string or a dictionary as a value (as we showed now), the value can be a number, a list or some other type.

Comment: Worked thank you. Do you have any tips for guides or videos that properly explain the syntax of it? I've had lots of issues finding good documentation. Most of my experimentation has been through just copying examples and doing trial and error.

Comment: I've updated the explanation, hope you understand it now.